# CSS Button shadow?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I am trying to rebuild a website from TYPO3 to Wordpress. 
The TYPO3 website is http://www.xsed.nl/
My WordPress rebuild is http://icestartup.com/testsites/site2/

If you see the main menu in TYPO 3 website you will notice a dark shadow behind the button. But I am not able to achieve that in my WordPress website.

Do you guys have any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: This image might make my doubt a bit more clear - http://i66.tinypic.com/96cc37.png

Comment: Just use the same images you had on the old website. Obtaining that effect on non-rectangular elements is tricky with CSS only. You'd need to use a `svg` for your buttons.

Comment: That is what i used. I cannot see the shadow in the old menu pictures.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: It might not seem obvious, but if you cannot see it it doesn't mean it's not there. Use the same background and you will see it.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You are right. Thanks man.

Comment: @Adam if my answer helps you then kindly upvote..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, in your previous site where you can see shadow you are using [image: old image]

which has shadow but in new site you are using

[image: new image]

which don't have shadow so try to switch the image and you are done...  hope it will help or let me know. Thank you